# std::set already contains the member even though it's different

Tags: c++, set

I wrote the following simple code:

```
std::set<Edge> edges;
Edge edge1("a","b");
Edge edge2("a","c");
edges.insert(edge1);
if (edges.find(edge2) != edges.end()) //edge2 already exists
    std::cout << "OH NO!";
```

Which has a bug since OH NO! gets printed even though `edge1` and `edge2` are different from each other.

Here's how I have implemented `operator ==` and `operator <` for `Edge`:

```
bool operator==(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) {
    return (e1.source == e2.source) && (e1.destination == e2.destination);
}

bool operator<(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) {
    return e1.source < e2.source;
}
```

What is causing this bug?

Comment: The `operator==` doesn't matter for comparison, equality is determined if neither compares less than the other. We need to see the `operator<` for `Edge`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau added it, how should I change it (Please Note I am looking to fix the bug but still to keep the edges sorted according to source (From A-Z) in the set)

Comment: Well, assuming "a" is the source, then your `<` operator is causing "equality" to be assumed.

Comment: You don't need `operator==`, you need `operator<`. `std::set` uses this to maintain the ordering. Two elements are _equivalent_ if neither precedes the other.

Comment: I got it thanks, but what changes should I make to operator< and maintain the same order in set (From A-Z according to source)

Comment: @daniel your `operator<` needs to take both `source` and `destination` into account, eg: `bool operator<(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) { return (e1.source == e2.source) ? (e1.destination < e2.destination) : (e1.source < e2.source); }`

Answer (score 6):

According to your `operator<`, `Edge("a","b")` and `Edge("a","c")` are equal. You need to tell the computer how you want to sort items when the first element is the same. The easiest way is to do a lexicographical sort. `std::tie` is great for this.

You'll need to `#include <tuple>` for this.

```
bool operator<(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) {
    return std::tie(e1.source, e1.destination) < std::tie(e2.source, e2.destination);
}
```

**Edit: Nah don't define the other operators in terms of `operator<` if it's simple enough.**

Or do. It's up to you. I'm undecided which style I prefer.

```
bool operator==(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) {
    return e1.source == e2.source && e1.destination == e2.destination;
}
```

is perfectly readable and maintainable. Maybe if it were more complicated I'd define it in terms of `operator<`.

---

**Old suggestion follows:**

It's also recommended to define all your other comparison functions in terms of `operator<`:

```
bool operator==(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) {
    return !(e1 < e2) && !(e2 < e1);
}
```

Not necessarily the most efficient (depending on your compiler), but unless you absolutely need it to be as fast as possible this keeps your code super maintainable.